# every $x\in V$ can be decomposed uniquely as $x=v+cz$,

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space and $L: V\mapsto R$ be a linear map. If $z\in V$ is not in the nullspace of $L$, show that every $x\in V$ can be decomposed uniquely as $x=v+cz$, where $v$ is in the nullspace of $L$ and $c$ is a scalar.

How can I start thinking on this problem? Please give some hints.

Edit : $V$ is finite dimensional

Comment: what is the dimension of the kernel for $L$?

Comment: Dimension of Kernel is dim of V - 1

Comment: use this information

Comment: @A B is your vector space finite dimensional? If yes please edit the question accordingly.

Comment: @Infinity_hunter Please see the edited question

Comment: @Exodd can you please give one more hint

Answer (score 1):

Take $z_1:=\dfrac z{L(z)}$ and set $c=L(x)$, then $x-cz_1\in\ker L$.

Also verify that no other $c$ works.

Answer (score 0):

Let the dimension of $V$ be $n$. Since dimension of $KerL = n -1$. Let $\{A_1,A_2,...A_{n-1}\} $ be a basis for $KerL$. By basis extension theorem extend this to a basis of $V$ by adding $A_n$ where $A_n $ not in $ KerL$. So for any $x \in V$ we have $x = a_1A_1 + \cdots + a_{n-1}A_{n-1} +a_n A_n$ and observe that for given $x$ each $a_i$ is unique. Now see that
$$
L (x ) = a_n L(A_n) \implies L(x - a_n A_n) = 0
$$
From this we conclude that $x - a_n A_n \in KerL$ so we can say that $x = v + cz$  where $v \in KerL$ , $c =a_n$ and $z = A_n$. To show uniqueness let $x = v_1 + a_nA_n = v_2 + b_n B_n$ then we see that $L(a_n A_n - b_nB_n) = 0$ but $a_n A_n - b_nB_n \in KerL$ only if $a_n A_n - b_nB_n = 0$. Now it follows from the axioms of vector space that $v_1 = v_2$ and we are done.